# How to check result set is empty in store procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using MS SQL Server 2014.. I have store procedure as;

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getId(
        @Api_Id INT
       ,@xmlRequest VARCHAR(max) out)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT xmlRequest FROM Api_request
        WHERE Api_id = @Api_id
END;
```

I want to add logic, If below statement return nothing:

SELECT xmlRequest FROM Api_request
    WHERE Api_id = @Api_id

For eg:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getId(
        @Api_Id INT
       ,@xmlRequest VARCHAR(max) out)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT xmlRequest FROM Api_request
        WHERE Api_id = @Api_id
   /*if result set empty*/
   /*  will add some logic here */
END;
```

How to check result set is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an `IF NOT EXISTS`:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT xmlRequest FROM Api_request
               WHERE Api_id = @Api_id)
BEGIN
   /*if result set empty*/
   /*  will add some logic here */
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Comment: @somtrivedi Glad I was able to help. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to use [@@ROWCOUNT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187316.aspx).  This returns the number of rows affected by the last statement.

```
IF (@@ROWCOUNT) > 0 
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Populated Resultset';
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT 'Empty Resultset';
    END
;
```

Personally I prefer @GiorgosBetsos's approach.  Combining the IF, NOT EXISTS, and QUERY into one statement is cleaner and easier to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can do like that:

```
IF (SELECT TOP 1 xmlRequest FROM Api_request WHERE Api_id = @Api_id) IS NULL
BEGIN
   /*if result set empty*/
   /*  will add some logic here */
END
```

Answer (score 0):

**If you are placing the results directly into a variable.  You could do:**

```
DECLARE @AGE INTEGER;
SELECT  @AGE = @AGE FROM people WHERE id= 1;
IF @AGE IS NULL:
-- execute your code here
```